# Distributed systems - signal LIFO

Tags: mutex, distributed-system, condition-variable

I have a doubt arround the paradigm of distributed systems.

Taking into consideration the condition variables that the signal operation unlocks. If we say that the processes are signaled in Last In First Out motion what vantages can we get from here and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantages and advantages related to what?... Assuming it is related to having no order I would say That a disadvantage is that if we have many processes being put to wait on that condition constantly we may see starvation because only the most recent processes will wake up making it impossible for the first ones to ever wake up unless processes stop being put to wait.

The advantages I'm not so certain, but we can always say that at least we have some order and the signal won't just wake a random process wich we may use for our bnefit.

There may be other advantages or disadvantages that I didn't think about so it may be best to wait for other answers.